A French - Italian movie with a trainer aircraft crash during the ww1
I'm looking for a 2000's French-Italian movie with the story of one of the first women pilots. She was young between 20-25, white, medium sized, could be red haired. The time in the movie was the years of 1st World War. A young French passinote woman wants to be a veterinary. She begs people to teach her how to do it but everyone deny it because of her sex. One day an experienced old guy accepts it and they start to the lessons. 
When they were flying to wilderness , they hit by Germans at the mountains between France and Italy. It was winter and there was a snow storm. Her teacher was dead and she was on her own. She got cold and injured. There were wild animals like wolves. She walked a few metres but then she passed out. The German soldiers were passing in a small village nearby saw this accident and tried to search the aircraft and survivors. An Italian man living in a cabin nearby also saw the accident and helped her to recover. 
His name could be Giuseppe. He was brunette, in his 30s and had some mental issues. He had bunch of animals also he was feeding wolves. He patched her wunds, changed her clothes and fed her. She was unconscious by the time. She woke up after 2-3 days and surprised about her saivor. The Germans eventually came to the cabin and he hide her from the soldiers. 
The name of the movie could be about girl and wolves. That's all I can remember.

Plot details, release year.. All things here. +1

Please try to come to grips with how punctuation works in written English language. The repairs people made to your questions should already give you an overview of how whitespace works around punctuation and make for a good learning example from which future questions can surely profit.

Sounds like The Maiden and the Wolves (La jeune fille et les loups) from 2008 with Laetitia Casta, though it takes place around World War One.

At the end of World War I, 20 year-old Angele is determined to become the first woman veterinarian. Her life is an adventurous one and she becomes the object of ruthless rivalry between the man she is supposed to marry, a visionary but unscrupulous industrialist and a simple man [called Giuseppe] who has withdrawn to the mountains to live among wolves, away from the madness of humans. Angele exploits this rivalry to attain her real goal: saving the wolves.

Here's the trailer, where you can see her in the plane:




Yes , this is the movie thank you ! I must have confused the wars and her profession .
